# jelly checkbox not persisting in the UI

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly, jenkins-cli

I have a jelly checkbox in in jenkins plugin :

```
<f:optionalBlock name="sendFcmPayload"
                                 help="/plugin/artifactory/help/common/help-sendFcmPayload.html"
                                 inline="true" checked="${instance.sendFcmPayload}"
                                 title="Send details of this build to FCM">
</f:optionalBlock>
```

I reference this value in the back end and the value received is correct in accordance to what I select in the UI, but the problem is every time I save the job configuration, the checkbox value in the UI doesn't persist.

Ive kept the optional block empty for now but based on it being checked or not I send a boolean value in the backend.

Comment: is the optional block empty?

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ Ive kept the optional block empty for now but based on it being checked or not I send a boolean value in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've left the body of the `f:optionalBlock` empty I assume all you need to do is bind the checkbox to a Boolean attribute. If so, the proper way to create the checkbox in the Jelly file is simply to use `f:checkbox` nested in `f:entry` like so:

```
<f:entry title="Send details of this build to FCM" field="sendFcmPayload">
    <f:checkbox/>
</f:entry>
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the checkbox behaves in a different way than other fields so it is not enough to specify the `title` and `field`. To persist a checkbox you also need to add an attribute `name` and `inline` to `f:entry` as follows:

```
<f:entry name="sendFcmPayload" inline="true" title="Send details of this build to FCM" field="sendFcmPayload">
    <f:checkbox />
</f:entry>
```